# Не работает подключение к базе данных в php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, openserver

Пишу вот такой вроде бы простой код подключение к базе данных в PhpMyAdmin и добавляю в поле name имя Том, но данные в базу не добавляются - выдает ошибку на странице[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот таблица и код подключения

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "epilog");
    $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $conn->query("INSERT INTO `teachers` (`name`) VALUES ('Tom')");

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Ошибку-то покажешь или мы поугадываем?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Field 'surname' doesn't have a default value in W:\domains\site\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 W:\domains\site\index.php(15): mysqli->query() #1 {main} thrown in W:\domains\site\index.php on line 15

Comment: Ну и если сообщение "Field 'surname' doesn't have a default value" перевести на русский, то что будет?

Comment: Поле «фамилия» не имеет значения по умолчанию

Но причем тут поле surname вообще если я добавляю в поле name

Comment: очевидно же, что поле surname является обязательным, раз без него не добавляется строка в БД

Comment: "Но причем тут поле surname вообще если я добавляю в поле name" При том, что когда в таблицу добавляется запись, то все поля должны иметь какое-то значение (в том числе задаваемое по умолчанию), либо NULL, если это указано в определении поля. Нельзя вставить запись только с именем. В поля фамилия, отчество, емейл что вставлять? Пустую строку? NULL? Строку "Не указано"?